# How to add text over video using ffmpeg in android using string array?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Below command is showing some error :

> ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "[in]drawtext=text='onLine1':[out]" -y out.avi

how to write that command using string array?

Comment: `showing some error`?

Comment: While using below command, a black color video is created.                                       {"ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", "/sdcard/videokit/in2.mp4", "-strict", "experimental", "-vf",
                        "drawtext=text=\'onLine1\': fontcolor=white",
                        "-map", "0:a", "-codec:v", "libx264", "-codec:a", "copy",
                        "/sdcard/Neha/outaa.mp4"}

Comment: Did you find any solution?